# Why use `code' for embracing code in a comment?

Tags: c, format, comments, glibc

I just read some glibc 2.22 source code (the source file at `/sysdeps/posix/readdir.c`) and came across this comment:

```
/* The only version of `struct dirent*' that lacks `d_reclen' is fixed-size.  */
```

<sub>(Newline removed.)</sub>

The weird emphasis of the type and identifier bugs me. Why not use just single-quotes or des accents graves? Is there some specific reason behind this? Might it be some character set conversion mistake?
I also searched the [glibc style guide](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Style_and_Conventions) but didn't found anything concerning code formatting in comments.

Comment: why the silent down-votes?

Comment: As I recall, this is a *nix convention from a time when ' slanted forward so ` and ' were opposite. I suspect it became enshrined in tools built to expect it.

Comment: Certainly it was arbitrarily downvoted.

Comment: @Grault An answer is appreciated. :-)

Comment: my gut says, that it is also easier to parse if you have separate opening and closing symbols (I'm not specifically talking about this exact case, when these are inside the comments, but in general using backticks and single quotes mixed -- as @Grault commented: it was used everywhere)

Comment: @cad I don't have a citation. :-( Some time back I attempted to find one and didn't get any satisfactory results. I wish I remembered where I saw the convention mentioned, though.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact the backtick character cannot be used in a valif C code? Just in case the comment is somehow leaking. Or just to indicate for some IDEs/tools that the following is an identifier/type/whatever for highlighting. .

Comment: @Grault I suspect you are right, and in fact it's so common on linux for error messages and comments that I even got used to doing it (*cad and I don't mean doing it like in the question you commented earlier today*). You can even check some of my answers where I do it. Knowing the reason would be amusing though.

Comment: also: to support @Grault's theory, look at a very early [VT220 glyphs-set](http://www.vt100.net/dec/vt220/glyphs) (almost the same as for VT100) -- as you can see, the single quote was exactly the opposite of the backtick

Comment: You can also see this style in Emacs documentation strings.

Comment: also, don't forget about [m4](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Quoted-strings.html#Quoted-strings), which takes advantage of having different opening and closing markers to allow nesting

Comment: Yes, it comes from the days when backtick and single-quote looked more like mirror images of each other -- these days it looks goofier (in most fonts).

Comment: some [background information](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html)

Comment: @Christoph So blame it on X, then?

Comment: GCC error messages usually use the leading back-tick and closing apostrophe.  I believe it harks back to the days of troff where the back-tick mapped to an opening (6) single quote and an apostrophe to the matching closing (9) single quote.  Thus, if formatted by troff, the output would look better.

Comment: @cad: X as well as early versions of the ASCII standard, where the apostrophe was known as *Apostrophe (Closing Single Quotation Mark Acute Accent)* and the backtick as *Grave Accent (Opening Single Quotation Mark)* - cf [RFC 20](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convention.

As you no doubt know, comments are ignored by the C compiler. They make no difference, but the developer who wrote that comment probably preferred their appearance to plain single quotes.

### ASCII

Using non-ASCII characters (unicode) in source code is a relatively new practice (moreso when English-authored source code is concerned), and there are still compatibility issues remaining in many programming language implementations. Unicode in *program input/output* is a different thing entirely (and that isn't perfect either). In program *source code,* unicode characters are still quite uncommon, and I doubt we'll see them make much of an appearance in older code like the POSIX header files for some time, yet.

### Source code filters

There are some source code filters, such as document generation packages like the the well-known [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc), that look for specific comment strings, such as `/**` to open a comment. Some of these programs *may* treat your `quoted strings' specially, but that quoting convention is older than most (all?) of the source code filters that might give them special treatment, so that's probably not it.

### Backticks for command substutution

There *is* a strong convention in many scripting languages (as well as StackExchange markdown!) to use backticks (``) to execute commands and include the output, such as in shell scripts:

```
echo "The current directory is `pwd`"
```

Which would output something like:

```
The current directory is /home/type_outcast
```

This may be part of the reason behind the convention, however I believe Cristoph has a point as well, about the quotes being balanced, similar to properly typeset opening and closing quotation marks.

So, again, and in a word: `convention'.

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna say in the "ASCII" part. Alright, they are new, but how does this explain why apostrophe and grave accent are used? Only grave accent is unicode or some Windows extension, right?

Comment: @cad The ASCII grave accent (#96 on any ASCII chart) was the *only* reasonable option to most programmers for a distinct opening quote in computer source code until very recently. Although the A is for "American", ASCII was (and is) the most widely *recognized* text encoding worldwide (Unicode is a superset of ASCII), especially when you consider all of the variants. Maintainers of the widely-deployed POSIX headers would probably not risk being inundated by encoding warning bug reports just to use a fancy quote character in a comment, so they keep it simple (which *always* means ASCII 32-126!)

Answer (score 2):

This goes back to early computer fonts, where backtick and apostrophe were displayed as mirror images. In fact, early versions of the ASCII standard blessed this usage.

Paraphrased from [RFC 20](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20), which is easier to get at than the actual standards like *USAS X3.4-1968*:

```
Column/Row  Symbol      Name
2/7         '           Apostrophe (Closing Single Quotation Mark Acute Accent)
6/0         `           Grave Accent (Opening Single Quotation Mark)
```

This heritage can also be seen in tools like `troff`, `m4` and `TeX`, which also used this quoting style originally.

Note that syntactically, there is a benefit to having different opening and closing marks: they can be nested properly.

Comment: RFC 20 ("ASCII format for Network Interchange") merely specifies the *use* of 7-bit ASCII over networks. It is most definitely *not* "the ASCII standard", like you said. My officially licensed hardcopy of *US ASCII, ANSI X3.4-1986* ([partial text here](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html), maybe a better source for your answer?) lists #96 as "GRAVE ACCENT", and not as a quotation mark, however you are correct regarding early versions. 1975 still had the "quote" text, though some unofficial versions were slow to update or chose not to. I've been using it as a quote since then, anyway. :-)

Comment: @type_outcast: the RFC was just the first 'official' document I could find online on short notice that mentioned this usage - the scans of the actual standard I took a look at were of a version that didn't

Comment: I completely understand. "ASCII charts" are very easy to come by, but the actual specs are not, probably due to the same scary legalese I had to sign to get mine. I won't link to something that says "copying and networking prohibited" on *every* one of its 27 pages. :-) If you want to quote the spec, though, you could just reference *USAS X3.4-1968* and include the text you have, which matches my copy of *X3.4-1968* verbatim (well, it's in all caps), and keep your RFC 20 link as an example of an ASCII chart with that wording. Or leave it. I'm not trying to pick nits, here, just help. ;-)

Comment: @type_outcast: I added a not about *X3.4-1968* andappreciate the confirmation that its actually in there